# Regex Expression to Match URL and Exclude Other

Tags: regex, redirect

Im trying to write a regex expression to match anything `(.*)/feed/` with the exception of `(.*)/author/feed/`

Currently, I have `(.*)/feed/(.*)` which works well to identify any string `/feed/` to redirect.  However, I dont want to exlude those that have `/author/(.*)/feed/`

For example - match `http://www.site.com/ANYTHING/feed/` but exclude `site.com/author/ANYTHING/feed/`

I should clarify that I'm not terribly familiar with regex expressions but this is actually for use within the Redirection plugin for wordpress which states "Full regular expression support."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance

Comment: What environment are you trying to make this work in? Many languages/servers/etc use slightly different regular expression languages...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, you may be able to use a negative look-behind assertion:

```
(.*)(?<!/author)/feed
```

The assertion, `(?<!/author)`, ensures that `/author` does not match behind the text `/feed`, but does not count it as being matched.

Comment: Thanks.  This almost works.  TO clarify, I want to block it from matching example.com/author/*/feed/  This works so as to block /author/feed/ but I actually need it to block /author/*/feed/ and DO want it to match for anything else with /feed/ at the end of the string.  So, should match example.com/*/*/feed/ example.com/*/feed/ etc....  Any chance you know that?  I tried adding a wildcard after author but didnt seem to work.  I think we're almost there though and would love it if you had an idea.